# How to apply .one() not for every object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having some difficulties with a certain task. I've got the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var Result = 0;
    var stop_process = false;
    $('img').click(function(){
            if( !stop_process ){
                if( $(this).hasClass( 'home' ) ){
                        stop_process = true;
                $('body').append('<div class="message">Your Result is: </div>' + Result);
            }
            if( $('img.home').length == 0 )
                        $(this).addClass('home');

            var $elem1 = $(this).parent();
            var $elem2 = $('span.last');
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
                if ($elem2.length > 0) {
                        connect($elem1[0], $elem2[0], "#0F0", 5);
                } else { 
                $elem1.addClass('last');
            }
            $('span').removeClass('last');
            $elem1.addClass('last');
        Result++;
        }
    });
```

I want to forbid a second click, so that I'll have a complete circle and I have gone through all objects once. If I apply .one() I get what I want, but I can't complete the circle, since the home object is still unclickable. Is there any way to solve this issue? To apply .one() to every object, but not the 'home' one?

Thanks in advance!

Whole code:

http://jsfiddle.net/N2Pdc/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [jQuery off](http://api.jquery.com/off/), you can build if statements around it to help you achieve this. Store in a variable the first elem you click, and have a counter, so you can make sure you can only click the first object (close the circle) when you have clicked all other elements before.

Comment: I'd really appreciate a code example, without the counter, just a quick scatch of the new structure. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **.one** you can use the jQuery filter **:not()** like `$(body:not(.home))`

Comment: Pardon me for the stupid question, but how do I insert the line into the code, so that it works.(I'm relatively new in the javascript)

Comment: maybe I misunderstood you... $('img:not(.home)').click(/*your function*/)